# How can I find a specific word and append an element in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am greenhand in middle of making a chrome extension, which will search for specific text from the entire web , and then append a button element.

Actually, it's a wordlist containing unfamiliar words, and I want to add a button near any of these unfamiliar words on each website.

I have implemented the manual word selection feature.

Like this: content-script.js

```
async function GetWordlist() {
    var { wordlist } = await chrome.storage.local.get(['wordlist'])
    wordlist = wordlist || []
    return wordlist
}


document.addEventListener('dblclick', async (event) => {
    var selection = window.getSelection()
    var selectedText = selection.toString().trim()
    if (selectedText.length > 0) {
        var wordlist = await GetWordlist()
        wordlist.push({
            content: selectedText,
            translation: `.... (Unfinish)`
        })
        await chrome.storage.local.set({wordlist})


        const range = selection.getRangeAt(0)
        console.log(range)

        const span = document.createElement('span');
        const button = document.createElement('button')
        {
            button.className = 'translated-word-btn'
            button.textContent = `$.... (Unfinish)`
            button.addEventListener('click', () => {
              //some features...eg.mark it familiar and delete this from the woldlist
            })
        }

            const originText = range.extractContents()
            span.appendChild(originText)
            span.appendChild(button)
            range.insertNode(span)
            const newRange = document.createRange()
            newRange.setStart(span, 0)
            newRange.setEnd(span, 1)

           //reselect the text
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
            window.getSelection().addRange(newRange)
        

    }
});
```

When I select a word, I can append an element because I have the range of the selection, and I can easily add a new element. However, I don't know how to search the entire page content. Help!

I get innerText and search from it ,but cant locate the position of an element in the DOM.
I have tried two APIs: document.body.innerHTML and document.body.innerText, but both of them either break the web structure or ignore the HTML elements。